# Can we write MyLocationListener outside the xxxActivity class?

Tags: android, location, android-location, locationlistener

Can i write MyLocationListener outside the MainActivity class? as the following example

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    ..onCreate(){
    .
    .
    loclis = new MyLocationListener(this); // Can i use it this way? 
    //if so, where is the best place to declare this line. 

    }
}
```

**MyLocationListener.class**

```
public class MyLocationListener implement LocationListener{
..
.//Constructor of MyLocationListener
}
```

Thanks you for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can declare a stand-alone class as a location listener. If you do, though, you'll probably want to have a mechanism of allowing your listener to call back into your activity if the location changes (or else your activity will never know that you got a location update):

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListner{

   private SomeInterface owner;

   public MyLocationListener(SomeInterface owner){
       this.owner = owner;
} 

}
```

Then your activity could look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SomeInterface{

    private LocationListner locListener;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        locListener = new MyLocationListener(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: by the way, if i would like to setTextvalue which is in R.layout.main in MainActivity.  Do i need to implement constructor like this: public MyLocationListener(Activity activity,SomeInterface owner){
       this.owner = owner;